# populando div com $.ajax, Erro

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte `HTML`:

```
<label class="labelPequeno" for="idPastor">Pastor</label> :
<select name="idPastor" id="idPastor" class="inputTextMedio required">
    <option value="" selected>Escolha o Pastor</option>
    <?php
        if ($pastores == null) echo "<option value=''>Sem Pastor</option>";
        else {
            foreach ($pastores as $pastor) echo "<option value=".$pastor["idPastor"].">".$pastor["nome"]."</option>";
        }       
     ?>     
</select> <br/>

<label class="labelPequeno" for="idRede">Rede</label> :
<select name="idRede" id="idRede" class="inputTextMedio required">
    <option value="" selected>Escolha o Pastor primero</option>
    <div class="optionsRedes"></div>
</select> <br/>
```

O objetivo agora é preencher o **combo select** `idRede` com o resultado do **$.ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#idPastor").on("change", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/buscarDados.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  idPastor: $("#idPastor").val()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','block');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                $("#imgCarregando").css('display','none');
                $(".optionsRedes").html(result);

            }

        });


    });

});
```

Mas a `div` não recebe valor algum.

Onde estou errando?

Obs.: quando faço:

```
alert(result);
```

Recebo retorno dos `options` corretamente.

```
<option value=1>Rede 1</option><option value=2>Rede 2</option>
```

Comment: isso não vai funcionar, precisa fazer o `append` mas no `select`. Tente assim: `$("#idRede").append(result);` e veja se isso já atende

Comment: funcionou! Mas, qual seria o correto? 1) Fazer um loop e fazer o append de cada option ou fazer o append das 2 options como uma string?]

Comment: depende de como recebe os dados. Se já recebe o html, não tem problema fazer o append direto do conteúdo html. Se recebesse um `json`, ai ficaria melhor fazer um loop e adicionar os itens um a um. Se fosse pra começar agora esse código, diria pra retornar um `json` com os dados e montar os options e adicionar um a um. O lado servidor devolve "dados" e o lado cliente monta da forma que precisa na página. Isso opinião minha ;-)

Comment: melhor fazer do teu jeito. Me parece mais correto. PHP = Dados. Se quiseres postar como resposta eu a aceito!

Comment: publiquei uma resposta com a solução para o append dos options

Comment: Só para esclarecer que você escreveu HTML inválido. O elemento `<select>` aceita apenas `<option>` ou `<optgroup>` como filhos, então sua `<div>` ia ser um problema de qualquer jeito ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Contexto_de_uso))

Answer (score 0):

Como o resultado da chamada `Ajax` já é um `html`, precisa então fazer o *append* desse `html` diretamente no elemento `select`, assim:

```
$("#idRede").append(result);
```

Ao adicionar na `div`, não faz com que os options façam parte do `select`.

Comment: Não seria melhor usar `$('#idRede').html(result)`? Se usar o `append` e o usuário trocar o valor do select anterior, os `<option>` vão começar a se acumular ao invés de serem substituídos.

Comment: perfeita a observação. Respondi usando o `append` porque no texto da pergunta, havia um option e o `ajax` retornou um novo, ou seja, me pareceu que estava trazendo novos itens, por isso o `append`, mas se retornar toda a lista, o `.html` será a opção certa